# what is this value called?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I've come across this operation that takes in two vectors

$a=(X_{a},Y_{a})$

and

$b=(X_{b},Y_{b})$

and returns a single number

$X_{a}\cdot Y_{b}-Y_{a}\cdot X_{b}$

Is this like 'a thing'? Like the dot-product? What would I need it for?

Explanation: it's used in the equation for line intersections that I am trying to understand.

[edit]: Excellent, thank you everybody, especially for telling me what this thing's actually good for! Shame I can only accept one answer :-/

Comment: what is $X,Y$???

Comment: the names that I've given the parts of each vector. X-coordinate of a, Y-coordinate of b etc.

Comment: It is the determinant of the matrix with columns $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everybody is correct that it is the determinant of a matrix, but it has a more direct geometric meaning - it is the area of the parallelogram formed by $0,a,b,a+b$, with a sign indicating the relative orientation of $a,b$.

The area is $|a||b|\sin\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is the angle between $a,b$, so this product is strongly related to the $\sin$ function.

Comment: I voted down because I think @Ross Millikan has given the best answer.

Comment: You don't have to vote something down because another answer is better. This answer isn't wrong, and provides some useful information.

Comment: @eccstartup. A very strange criterion for downvoting, IMO. Why then didn't you downvote the other answers as well? Foo's point is well taken.

Comment: @RickDecker I actually agree with that sort of downvoting, sometimes. I usually only do it if I think the selected answer was sloppy or inarticulate (even if correct) and there was a much clearer answer elsewhere, but I understand the impulse - he wants later readers to notice the other answer, not just the "checked" answer.  I can take the hit :)

Comment: @RickDecker I clicked downvoting by mistake, and the site told me to add a reason. So I added a reason why I downwoted.

Comment: Ah, if it was just an accident, you can always revert your downvote by clicking on the down arrow again. @eccstartup :) Usually, you can only change a vote within a certain window, but since I made an edit, you should be able to change your vote.

Comment: Well, reverting will change -1 to +1 not 0, and I did it again.@ThomasAndrews

Comment: @eccstartup That means you clicked the up arrow, not the down arrow again. If you downvote, the way to cancel your downvote is, confusingly, to click the downvote button again, not to click the upvote button.

Answer (score 5):

If you view your vectors as being in the $xy$ plane of $\Bbb R^3$, so $a=(Xa,Ya,0)$ the result is the $z$ component of the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) $a \times b$.  The other two components will be zero.

Answer (score 1):

The operation you're speaking of is the result of concatenating the two vectors to form a matrix, and then taking its determinant.

Comment: In particular, it is the area of the parallelograph form by $0,a,b,a+b$

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the determinant of the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec X ~~~ \vec Y
\end{bmatrix}
~=~
\begin{bmatrix}
Xa & Ya \\
Xb & Yb
\end{bmatrix}
$$

### EDIT:

If you look for an application, then
$$
{\rm det}\big[\,\vec X~~\vec Y\,\big]~=~0
\quad\text{iff}\quad
\vec X ~//~\vec Y
$$
i.e. it returns $0$ if and only if the vectors are parallel.

Comment: Ok, other people posted first and more comprehensive answers...

Answer (score 1):

If you form a matrix with $a,b$ as its two rows the this is the determinant of the matrix.

det$\begin {pmatrix}
x_a&y_a\\
x_b&y_b\\
\end{pmatrix}=x_ay_b-y_ax_b$

If $a=(x_a,y_a),b=(x_b,y_b)$ lie on two lines(or on the same line )which are parallel to each other then $\begin {pmatrix}
x_a&y_a\\
x_b&y_b\\
\end{pmatrix}=0$ because in that case $a=kb\Rightarrow (x_a,y_a)=(kx_b,ky_b)\Rightarrow x_ay_b-y_ax_b=0$ for some $k\in R$